# Caching approach for a cluster of servers

Tags: java, caching, jboss, memcached, distributed-caching

I have a Java application deployed on a cluster of JBoss AS 5.1 which requires a lot (> 3 GB) of data to be cached.
Right now the server cluster has just 2 nodes (separate machines).
Here are specific requirements:

**Both nodes should not require data to be loaded into cache (i.e., there should either be replication or cache should reside on a separate server)**

The data should never expire.

*Both of the above requirements are REALLY important for the application. I'd be thankful if the suggestion would be made keeping both of these in mind.*
I should also add a third requirement:

ease of use

The application was initially using Hashmap. I tried replacing the hashmap with JBoss Cache 3.2.1 for its replication and thread safety features. But i'm not really happy with JBoss Cache performance. Also when i load the data in the cache the 8 Gig of RAM is almost entirely being used (most of it is used by the cache entries).

I'd like to hear the experience of people who have handled such kind of caching scenario themselves. Thanks for your time in advance.

Comment: I see that people are viewing the question but I have no answers/suggestions yet. I'm not asking for a complete solution, a good suggestion perhaps. Please let me know if giving out more details will help you in your suggestions.

Comment: Why do you not want to use memcached?

Comment: @Perception: I don't have much experience with memcached but isn't it true that memcached will expire the data in cache based on LRU (or any other algo) when the load increases? I'm trying to avoid this scenario because i need a persistent store which does not expire data automatically. Please let me know if you think memcached will fulfill all my requirements. After reading the answer below I think i need to add 'ease of use' to the list above too :)

Answer (score 2):

You can try out using GigaSpaces XAP datagrid is a replicated cache. It is very highly performant.

http://www.gigaspaces.com/datagrid

Answer (score 0):

If you want a cache that provides a Java HashMap interface and can easily support gigabytes of cache data, with no expiry, then check out Oracle Coherence. This would use the Coherence "distributed cache" option (which is the default configuration). For more info, see: http://coherence.oracle.com/

- Elastic. Just add nodes. Auto-discovery. Auto-load-balancing. No data loss. No interruption. Every time you add a node, you get more data capacity and more throughput.
- Use both RAM and flash. Transparently. Easily handle 10s or even 100s of gigabytes per Coherence node (e.g. up to a TB or more per physical server).
- Automatic high availability (HA). Kill a process, no data loss. Kill a server, no data loss.
- Datacenter continuous availability (CA). Kill a data center, no data loss.

*For the sake of full disclosure, I work at Oracle. The opinions and views expressed in this post are my own, and do not necessarily reflect the opinions or views of my employer.*

Answer (score -2):

I have 'solved' this problem before (work code, can't show you)... but, I can tell you this much:

- with large volumes, a large amount of memory is used in overhead in HashMaps.
- you can save a lot of memory by replacing java.util.* classes with smart uses of arrays.
- every time you have memory allocations you also have to scan/collect that memory in the GC, so saving memory also improves performance.

Wherever you can, use arrays....

Edit: Apparently the concept of Hash Maps has been forgotten.... Has the Java implementation of HashMap made people believe it is the only way? A structured set of arrays, with a hash function, and a binary sort.... all basic structures... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table

One array to add keys to. A parallel array to store the values in, and an int-based hash table to make a fast lookup in to the key array...

Computer Science - maybe second year ;-)

Edit again: I used to core concepts I have described in the JDOM project here: https://github.com/hunterhacker/jdom/blob/master/core/src/java/org/jdom2/StringBin.java

Comment: Thanks for the tip but as per the application design i'd need a key-value store, something which supports replication to all nodes in the cluster. Performance and memory footprint is a big concern. I'm looking at Redis for now. Will update this thread with my findings.

Comment: You have a good point about using arrays. Again, the very first point in my requirements says I need replication of cache to all the nodes in the cluster. Honestly, for now i'm not really worried about the performance of Hashmap.